# How to show the optgroup value + option value as the selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Take a look at the following select:

```
<select>
<optgroup label="A">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
<option value="">3</option>
<optgroup label="B">
<option value="">4</option>
<option value="">5</option>
<option value="">6</option>
</select>
```

When any element is selected I would like to display its label + value in the selection instead of just value. So if 4 is selected I would like the selection to show B - 4

Comment: close your optgroup tags properly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you need the selected value back to its original value... try this...
http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/sxvW2/2/

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var opt = $(this).find(':selected');
    var sel = opt.text();
    var og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    //alert(sel);
    //alert(og);

    $(this).blur().find(':selected').text(sel + '-' + og);

});

$('select').focus(function () {
    $(this).find('option').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
        t=$(this).text().split('-');
        $(this).text(t[0]);

    });

});
```

UPDATE
using the select2 plugin you can do the following
http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/bJxFR/4/

```
function format(item) {
       opt = $('select').find(':selected');
       sel = opt.text();
       og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
      return item.text+'-'+og;

}
$("select").select2({
formatSelection: format,
escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it using the Select2 jquery plugin?

Comment: you'll have to modify the plugins source code or trigger the above code in a select2-plugin callback (if any).

Comment: Your demo has a bug (I don't understand why), but changing `opt` to `opt = $(item.element);` fixes it.

Comment: Addition of selected value and bug fix based on comment by @ArturoTorresSánchez : http://jsfiddle.net/bJxFR/58/

Answer (score 1):

Its hacky to update the selected value but check out this demo

**[Hacky Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4HJd4/4/)**

```
$('#select').change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $('#select option:selected');
    var label = selectedOption.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    var selectText = selectedOption.text();

    var length = $(this).find(':selected').text().length;

    if (length < 2) {
        $(this).find(':selected').text(label + ' - ' + selectText);
    }
});
```

Comment: How would it be using Select2?

Comment: i didn't get you.. I have added the demo, please look at that

Comment: That's great, now try setting the selects value to a value that isn't in any of the options !

Comment: I'm using the Select2 plugin for jquery as stated above. It needs to be done using its options or it wouldn't work.

Comment: oops I missed that .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sxvW2/)

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="A">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
        <option value="">3</option>
        <optgroup label="B">
            <option value="">4</option>
            <option value="">5</option>
            <option value="">6</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var opt = $(this).find(':selected');
    var sel = opt.text();
    var og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    //alert(sel);
    //alert(og);

    $(this).find(':selected').text(sel + '-' + og);

});
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it using the Select2 jquery plugin?

Comment: Please put together a jsfiddle example, fully mocked-up, and including the Select2 plugin (you should be able to load the js via the [jsDelivr CDN site](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!select2) -- use the external resources accordion tab and paste the URL minus the `http:` prefix.

Comment: @user1029829 Here, I mocked-up [an empty jsFiddle shell](http://jsfiddle.net/bJxFR/) for your question, with the Select2 plugin pre-loaded. (See External Resources accordion). Just add HTML/jQuery code to demonstrate what is not working, and UPDATE. Then edit your original question and post the revised URL as a jsFiddle link. `[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xxxxxx/)`

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/bJxFR/3/ Try to select any of the values. If you select 1, the dropdown will say 1, if you select 5 it will say 5. I want it to say A - 1 or B - 5.

Comment: Doesn't work when selecting the same option twice. I didn't find a solution for that particular issue though.