# How to make grouped output of results in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Tell me how to display a grouped result using `select2` in this form, now I have approximately the same representation

[image]

This is my code

```js
$('[data-plugin-select2]')
  .select2()
  .on('select2:select', function(e) {
    console.log(e.params.data.element);
  });
```

```css
select {
  width: 500px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select multiple data-plugin-select2>
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Closest thing I can do for you is this : https://jsfiddle.net/aeLk6mnx/ from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017750/jquery-select2-show-optgroup-label-when-selected as I don't think what you're trying to do is easily doable